# Getting exceptions with simple hello worldwind java app

Tags: java, eclipse, worldwind

Let me preface this by saying I'm very new to Java, eclipse and worldwind.

So, I've got a bare bones java app. I imported worldwind.jar into the build path. Created a simple JFrame, code below, and added the following to the Project > properties > Run/Debug settings > Arguments > VM arguments :

> -Djava.library.path=Path\To\My\Worldwind\Directory

Here is the JFrame source

```
public class TestMap extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TestMap frame = new TestMap();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public TestMap() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
    contentPane.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    WorldWindowGLCanvas worldWindowGLCanvas = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
    splitPane.setRightComponent(worldWindowGLCanvas);

    Model m = (Model)WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
}

}
```

When I run the program, the worldwind panel is black, and i get exceptions streaming through the console output.

Apr 18, 2012 2:44:18 PM gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindowGLAutoDrawable display
SEVERE: Exception while attempting to repaint WorldWindow
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.render.DrawContextImpl.getGlobe(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.view.BasicView.apply(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.AbstractSceneController.applyView(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.BasicSceneController.doRepaint(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.AbstractSceneController.repaint(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindowGLAutoDrawable.doDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindowGLAutoDrawable.display(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:78)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$DisplayAction.run(GLCanvas.java:288)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:194)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.maybeDoSingleThreadedWorkaround(GLCanvas.java:265)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:130)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:142)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I'm on a 64bit machine, I downloaded the AMD64 version of jogl and put the .dll's in the worldwind folder. That worked to get the demo app running.

Comment: I think I see the problem... there is no `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you: http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2011/03/10/how-to-create-a-cross-platform-application-with-nasa-worldwind-netbeans-platform/

Very, long time ago I work with WWJ :)

From what I can see you must set the model to the WWJ instance:

```
Model model = (Model)WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
WorldWindowGLCanvas wwj = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
wwj.setModel(model);
```

or

```
WorldWindowGLCanvas worldWindCanvas = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();
worldWindCanvas.setModel(new BasicModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a graphics driver problem.  I saw this behavior when I tried to run a worldwind app on a machine with just the standard windows 7 graphics driver.  Upgrading to the latest nvidia driver (because the machine had an invidia card) solved this issue.

With worldwind 2, you can just double-click the worldwindx jar and if there are troubles messages will pop up telling you what functions are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be related with your world Model. You created a model but you did not add this model into your WorlWindow.

```
Model model = (Model)WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
worldWindowGLJPanel.setModel(model);
```

You can check other examples [here](https://github.com/nasa/World-Wind-Java/tree/master/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples)

Btw, any further researchers: 
The Severe Exception :  Exception while attempting to repaint WorldWindow .
It is not related with yout graphic cards. You are most probably trying to do multiple animations or multiple task on the same time. For example, while you are trying to move your camera position with Util.goTo function, you may try to add some Tactical Symbol on the WorldWindow.

Remember that OpenGl works on one main thread.